# foundation-rails + jquery + turbolinks: works only on page load and not after

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, turbolinks

I read through the 10 pages of this forum and nothing seems to solve my problem. I narrowed down my code to the strict minimal to be able to analyse my problem and I feel close to the solution but I lack knowledge in the interactions in between those 3 (jQuery, turbolinks and foundation-rails).

To make life easier for future readers, here are the versions I'm using:
- `rails` 5.1.2
- `turbolinks` 5.0.1
- `foundation-rails` 6.4.1.2
- `jquery-rails` 4.3.2

Load sequence in `application.js`

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require foundation
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require_tree .
```

Event trigger in `application.js`

```
 $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
   console.log("turbolinks:load");
   $(function(){ 
     console.log("JQuery");
     $(document).foundation();
   });
 });
```

Below a scenario of what happens in my console. The text between asterisk (*) are action in my side:

```
*enter url in browser*
turbolinks:load
JQuery                          (1)
*clicks on a link in the app*
turbolinks:load
JQuery                          (2)
*clicks on a link in the app*
turbolinks:load
JQuery                          (3)
*refreshes the page (=new HTTP GET request)
turbolinks:load
JQuery                          (4)
```

The sticky menu works (=is sticky) at step (1) and (4). During steps (2) and (3) it acts as if it wasn't parsed by foundation. You can reproduce it at https://reshel.herokuapp.com

Any idea if this is the normal behaviour or if this is a bug / problem.

File `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.4.1"

gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development]

# Core
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'json'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'pg'

# Front End
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'modernizr-rails'
gem "typedjs-rails", "~> 1.0.4"
gem 'toastr-rails'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'will_paginate-foundation'

# Dashboard
gem 'forest_liana'

# External services
# gem 'intercom-rails'
# gem 'intercom'
# gem 'stripe'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :production, :staging do
  gem 'rack-timeout'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end
```